# EACCES (Permission denied @ rb_sysopen on ElasticBeanStalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, access-denied, rails-activejob

I have a Rails ActiveJob that attempts to write some files.  When the ActiveJob is invoked by the controller, it fails with the above error, trying to write a file as follows: Errno::EACCES (Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/ec2-user/scrubarea/landing/5mBs8mq85ZFKVnqijeKZuNuh).

This happens even if the directory has 777 permissions.

However, if I ssh into the EC2 image, access the Rails console, and run the job using perform_now, it works.

Is there some other AWS security that won't let an application write files?

Comment: it's look like dependent on user's permission, please check user when you run manually and user when run by system.

Comment: Running manually, it's EC2-USER, and running under the Rails application, it's webapp.  I tried changing ownership of the directories to webapp,  but that didn't work.  I tried adding webapp to the group EC2-USER, but that didn't work.

Comment: But, when I changed an environmental parameter to send the files to /var/tmp/scrubarea, it **did** work!  And maybe that's the right answer, given that these files are short-lived, since they're copied to S3 as the last step in the job.

Comment: you mean issue is resolved by just move file to `/var/tmp/scrubarea`?

Comment: That was one of many.  I did as you suggested--delving into permissions when running as ec2-user, vs. when the Rails job runs, which is under user webapp.  I finally resolved it my putting commands into a .ebextensions config file to create the scrubarea directories, then doing a chmod to allow writing for the ec2-user group, then doing a chmod so that ec2-user owned the directories, and, last, adding webapp to the ec2-user group.